# How to encode the password in Gatling?

Tags: base64, gatling, password-encryption

I have a requirement in my project to encode the password being sent in the login request. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the credentials in a file as key-value pair. Read the file in vector and then decode the value. The value can be stored in a session and can be used in your Gatling request as below:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.structure.ChainBuilder
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._
import io.gatling.jsonpath._
import Headers._
import scala.collection._
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.LocalDate

import io.gatling.core.feeder._
import java.util.Base64
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import scala.util.matching.Regex

object TestClass {

//Now you can use below code to read the credential file,

  val recordsByEnv: Map[String, Seq[Record[Any]]] =
    csv("/User/sandy/data/userdetails.csv").readRecords.groupBy { record =>
      record("env").toString
    }
  val passwordByEnv: Map[String, Seq[Any]] = recordsByEnv.mapValues { records =>
    records.map { record =>
      record("password")
    }
  }
  val password_v = (passwordByEnv.get("env_name").toString)
  val password_encoded = password_v.substring(12, (password_v.length - 2))
  val credentials = new String(Base64.getDecoder.decode(password_encoded))
  //Store the decoded value in session variable
    .exec(session => session.set("password", credentials))
    .exec(
      http("Authorization")
        .post("https://XXXX.xxxxxx.com")
        .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .formParam("password", "${password}")
        .formParam("username", "USERNAME")
    )
//Below is user details file look like below
//env_name,encoded_password

}
```